# List of available **kwargs

Tags: python

In the python help documents I often see a Signature line with function name and named parameters, then you will see **kwarg (keyword arguments).

```
list?
```

Which prints to the help docstring:

```
Init signature: list(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:     
list() -> new empty list
list(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items
Type:           type
```

Is there a way to list the available keywords and/or args that can be passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope - `*args` and `**kwargs` are catch-all arguments where the former one will capture every extra unnamed argument in a `list`, and the latter will capture every named argument in a `dict`.

People who write functions/methods utilizing one or both of these special capture arguments decide what to do with them so, unless you look through their code, if they haven't provided documentation for their functions/methods you cannot know what is their intention or what they expect to get.

Answer (score 1):

There is [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module, which can help you:

```
>>> inspect.getargspec(aMethod)
(['arg1', 'arg2'], None, None, None)
```

For builtin methods you can use `__doc__` argument:

```
>>> list.__doc__
"list() -> new empty list\nlist(iterable) -> new list initialized from iterable's items"
```